# Scaling axis in addplot

Tags: pgfplots, scaling

When using the following code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=blue,only marks,mark size=0.5] file[x index=0, y index=1]{bla.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where bla.text are some coordinates of points in [0,1]x[0,1], axis are not exactly in the good scaling and I haven't a square-box : the y axis is a bit bigger than the x axis.

Is there a command that could fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1]`? If the data is not exactly "touching" 0 and 1 on every axis, you can have differences created by the autoscaling.

Comment: Using the `axis equal` might help as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments